# Контейнеры в Си

Tags: структуры-данных, c

Я ищу простой и изящный способ организации контейнеров в Си. Большинство проблем возникает из-за невозможности получения RTI. Так, например, предположим, что есть универсальная структура, которая хранит данные и для `QUEUE`, и для `STACK`. Понятно, что обе такие структуры поддерживают `PUSH` и `POP` операции. Но реализованы они в них по-разному.

Внимание, вопрос: как оставить общий интерфейс, но избежать дублирования кода? Вставлять `switch...case` внутрь `PUSH` и `POP` тоже не хочется.

Answer (score 1):

Можно организовать что-то вроде полиморфизма:

```
struct SequenceContainer {
    union {
        struct Stack stack;
        struct Queue queue;
    } container;
    void (*init)(struct SequenceContainer *hcontainer);
    void (*push)(struct SequenceContainer *hcontainer, const SequenceContainer_etype *elem);
};
struct SequenceContainer *create_queue(void) {
    struct SequenceContainer *p = malloc(sizeof(struct SequenceContainer));
    if (p != NULL) {
        p->init = queue_init;
        p->push = queue_push;

        p->init(p);
    }

    return p;
}
```

Только придется внимательно следить за использованием этого контейнера - возможности C в диагностике несоответствия типов ограничены. Поэтому для таких конструкций больше подходит C++.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте другой подход.

Вставляйте структуру, реализующую контейнер прямо в пользовательскую структуру данных. Это удобно еще и тем, что одни и те же данные пользователя можно одновременно помещать в разные контейнеры.

Для примера можете посмотреть на [хэш-таблицу](http://pastebin.com/n5Cf0S4W) и [двусвязный список](http://pastebin.com/EVwuTAiF) (сделан по мотивам известного в Linux циклического списка [include/linux/list.h](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~baker/devices/lxr/http/source/linux/include/linux/list.h))